# Displaying a specific Date in a DropDown from a range Dates in asp.net: Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate a dropdown , where I want the default selected value to be the sysdate selected. For example if I have 4 results in the dropdown

Wednesday,January 22,2013

Thursday,January 23,2013

***Friday,January 24,2013***

Saturday,January 25,2013

I want todays date ***Friday,January 24,2013*** to be the default selected value. Now to achieve that I have written code like below in my method.

```
            string DateofNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy"); 
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        string sqlQuery = "select distinct duty_date from duty_rota where duty_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - 40 AND SYSDATE + 365 order by duty_date";
        using (OracleConnection conn = new AppConfig().GetConnection())
        {
            try
            {
               conn.Open();
                using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
                {
                    using (OracleDataAdapter ODA = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        ODA.Fill(table);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Not Connected" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        DropDownList1.DataSource = table;
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "duty_date";
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "duty_date";
        DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy}";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(DateofNow).Selected = true;
```

But I am getting *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"* Error. I am clueless where I am going wrong exactly. Can somebody please help me in this.

Comment: At what line are you getting the exception?

Comment: I guess in the last line if I exclude "DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(DateofNow).Selected = true;" it is running fine.

Comment: Are you sure the dropdownlist has all the dates with year 2013? Not 2014?

Comment: That means that `FindByText` fails to find the list item. Make sure drop down really contains the value you are looking for.

Comment: @ekad it has 14 data specifically. Would that cause a problem. The code is running fine till last line. How ever in the last line I am getting the mentioned error.

Comment: Try commenting out the `FindByText` line, and seeing exactly what `<option>` items are sent to the browser... then you might be able to see why your `DateofNow` isn't matching any of the text values

Comment: @Andrei thanks, but I formatted the Dropdown for that
`DropDownList1.DataValueField = "duty_date";
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "duty_date";
        DropDownList1.DataTextFormatString = "{0:dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy}";`
and again formatted the DateString 
`string DateofNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy");`
is anywhere I am going wrong?

Comment: I believe `DateofNow` would be `Friday,January 24,2014` if you run the above code today, but if the dropdownlist doesn't have any items with the exactly same text, it will be error. You need to check the query results, is there any records with this exact value: `Friday,January 24,2014`

Comment: Good spot @ekad - the `2013` in the dropdown won't match the `2014` in `DateofNow`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up guys, I guess its a data problem. Fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you run the above code today, it's because `DateofNow` value is `Friday,January 24,2014` but none of the DropDownList items has the exact same value. Since the query result may not contain today's date, I would suggest changing this line:

```
DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(DateofNow).Selected = true;
```

to this:

```
if (DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(DateofNow) != null)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.FindByText(DateofNow).Selected = true;
}
```

so if the query result doesn't contain today's date, you won't get the same error again and the DropDownList won't select any of its items.